# Free memory after running trained neural network model on web application

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, torchvision

I am running a demo web application using pre-trained  network. The problem I have is that for each image I test against the network, the memory is increased a lot and never freed, so I have to restart the web server in order to free memory out of old objects I do not use any more. This is the network I run:

```
from torchvision import models

fcn = models.segmentation.fcn_resnet101(pretrained=True).eval()
```

And this is the code where most significant part of memory accumulated:

```
out = net(inp)['out']
```

Where `net` is an alias (function param) for `fcn` and `inp` is image input converted to the appropriate form to use by network model.

This works on apache web server using flask and wsgi. I have a lot of code, so I put only the most important. I don't know how to fix the problem and therefore if some additional piece code is important to show here, I don't know which one.

I did some research and found some "quick" solutions (some are here on SO), but they did not help a lot. This is what I tried, for example. I separated model call result and assigned it to explicit variable, then used garbage cleaner:

```
mr = net(inp)
out = mr['out']
```

and then

```
del net
del mr
gc.collect()
```

It did not help. I assume the residing objects are created under external model code and I expect to see some solution to free memory out of those objects using nn model functions, but not sure if I am in a right direction.

Also I consider some "standard" way to do it in python, such as creating separate thread or something similar method to better control memory. I am not an expert here, so a good advice will be appreciated. And it has to work with apache, flask and wsgi_mod as well.

Comment: are you loading the model again and again when each image is checked against the model ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 good point, thank you, I will change this to use only once... I am new to python based web development and flask in particular, but I assume it will be alive until apache stops and shared by all web users right?

Comment: @sahasrara62 using network only once is a good point and works much faster, but the memory is still accumulated. Probably this solution is good for a good web server because at some point accumulation shows down, but I have limited memory on my public server and in my case it's better to load network each time and clean after each use rather then keep one instance and get still have memory usage increased

Comment: create one instace of the model, when youu load the image , check that iimge agianst that model instance only, once checked you can remove that image from memory and keep the instace alive, you can schedule a job to load the instace if incase it  got updated

Comment: this does not help, once again this is good point, but accumulating more and more memory, so not working for my specific environment: I have 1 Gig of memory on my AWS, about 100 Mb taken, when I create a model instance, half Gig already taken, after I run a first image it's about 900 Mb and I cannot run the second image. Sometimes I can run second, but cannot run third. When I work with my 4 Gig local VM your solution helps because it runs faster and memory increase slows down at a point around 3 Gig. So in my case I need to fully cleanup memory after each image test.